# Kotlin - Set zoom level google map Android Studio

Tags: api, dictionary, zoom-sdk

I've added the Google Map API and added my markers, but when the app is run, it is zoomed out quite a lot. I tried researching but I can't find what I need. Can someone please tell me how to set the zoom level once the map is loaded? E.g, it should show only a city not the whole world.

Here's my fragment code

```
package com.example.myassignment.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.myassignment.R
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_destinations.*

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class DestinationsFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.onResume()

        mapView.getMapAsync(this)

    }
    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        map?.let {
            googleMap = it
        }
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        val stokeOnTrent = LatLng(53.025780,-2.177390)
        val stokeCobrdige = LatLng(53.029380,-2.188740)
        
        // Here's my markers
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(stokeOnTrent).title("Stoke Center"))
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(stokeCobrdige).title("Cobridge - Stoke"))
        googleMap.minZoomLevel
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(stokeOnTrent))
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_destinations, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment DestinationsFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            DestinationsFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't resolve this already, you need to use the function **`newLatLngZoom()`** instead of `newLatLng()` and provide the zoom level - 10.

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(stokeOnTrent, someZoomLevel))
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-maps#4), but it says:

> `val homeLatLng = LatLng(latitude, longitude)`
>
> `val zoomLevel = 15f`
>
> The zoom level controls how zoomed in you are on the map. The following list gives you an idea of what level of detail each level of zoom shows:
>
> 1: World
>
> 5: Landmass/continent
>
> 10: City
>
> 15: Streets
>
> 20: Buildings
>
> Move the camera to `homeLatLng` by calling the `moveCamera()` function on the map object and pass in a `CameraUpdate` object using `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom()`. Pass in the `homeLatLng` object and the `zoomLevel`.
>
> `map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(homeLatLng, zoomLevel))`